# Starting out doing server side things - what languages and techniques to choose?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, database, server-side

I've been doing html, css and javascript for quite a long time, mostly for my very own enjoyment. I would say I know fairly much, I've created many simple games and apps and experiments with javascript. However there is only so much that is possible to do in the browser, for any more "complete" websites I am constantly confronted with my ignorance on server side programming.

So, what do I need. I need to get my head around how to use databases and how to use some server side programming language, I guess. What is the right choice? What should I avoid?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

[PHP](http://php.net/) and [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) have a pretty low barrier to entry (they're both free and ubiquitous).  I'd start with those, since most hosts provide them for you.  As an added bonus, they work really well together (and PHP isn't very hard to learn coming from a web development background).

[Head First SQL](http://headfirstlabs.com/books/hfsql/) is a great book for learning MySQL.  All of the examples in the book are done on MySQL.  The book even explains where to get it and how to install it.  As for PHP, the [introductory tutorial](https://www.php.net/tut.php) at official website is the best place to learn it.

Update: [Head First PHP & MySQL](http://www.amazon.ca/Head-First-MySQL-Lynn-Beighley/dp/0596006306) is now available.  I haven't read this one yet, but other books in the series and by the same author are great for learning new languages from scratch.

Answer (score 5):

Download [Python](http://www.python.org).  Learn the Python language.  Learn Object-Oriented programming.

Python includes [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/), this makes it easier to Learn the SQL language.

Download the [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com) framework.  This makes it easy to write server-side applications that work simply and reliably.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest PHP. Not because it's the best, most modern or cleanest language out there, but because it is easy to learn for someone coming from pure HTML.

You begin by just adding tiny bits of PHP to your regular HTML and magic happens :)

Answer (score 2):

Ruby is a fantastic language and the frameworks for web stuff generally teach you some good practices. [Try it](http://tryruby.hobix.com/). The [Learn to program book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0976694042) uses Ruby, maybe you'd like to check it out.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed in your question you mention that you've been using javascript. If you're comfortable progamming javascript, I've recently begun working with server side javascript in the form of [EJScript](http://www.ejscript.org/) on linux and using jscript on windows. It's been fairly painless, and the documentation has been pretty good so far on both.
If you're more interested in learning this with another technology then Django & Python or ASP.NET & C# (or IronPython) are both fairly low barrier to entry platforms available on windows, *nix, etc...

Answer (score 0):

I would say that if you're comfortable working in Linux, then go for PHP and MySQL.  If you aren't comfortable working in Linux, then download the free [Visual Web Developer](http://www.microsoft.com/express/vwd/) version of Visual Studio Express, and get started using that.  This lets you program in VB.Net or C#, and use the .Net web development framework.  It's really miles ahead of anything PHP in terms of how nice a platform it is to work on.  There's also a free developer edition of SQL Server that lets you store up to 4 GB of data.

There's plenty of .Net hosts out there now too. Although, due to increased license costs, Windows hosting plans will usually cost more and give you less space/bandwidth than Linux hosting plans, you can still get enough room to play around with and deploy some apps on the web.  If you develop something really cool, and outgrow what your hosting account provides, it's probably time to upgrade to a VPS, and post ads on your site to start paying the bills

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend PHP for folks who are familiar with HTML but are newish to programming.  Here's why:

I'm currently an ASP.Net developer, and I think that ASP.Net abstracts waaaaay to much to make it a good first programming environment.  I say learn how to generate and manipulate straight HTML with a language like PHP instead of trying to understand GridViews, etc., which have no bearing or relevance to programming in the broader sense.

I wouldn't say ASP.Net is "the Dark Path" or anything, but if you start out by learning it, you'll tend to favor the warm and insulating arms of the framework.  ASP.Net is pretty much a code-generator when compared to more explicit (some would say reckless, messy, and tedious, but I'm not one of them) methods like PHP.

With PHP you'll see the effect your code has on the actual HTML when you view source.  With an ASP.Net page, you'll be baffled by the amount and complexity of the HTML it spits out.

After you get your hands dirty in PHP, you can explore the pros and cons of frameworks like ASP.Net that "do a lot of the work for you".

Answer (score 0):

I was exactly in your situation 3 to 4 years ago and, like some of the commentators suggest, I tried PHP because of its low barrier of entry.

That was a mistake! Oh sure I was able to achieve some things here and there, including using a contact form from a book which was so flawed that it was later hijacked by big time spammers and got my domain banned from most email servers out there.

Later on I tried to learn how to create dotabase driven sites with object oriented programming following the guidance of the excellent books, blog posts, and forums from [Sitepoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/) and other sources. It was just too hard for my little brain. I just could not do it.

So what happened? 2 1/2 years ago I decided to learn Rails, which had just turned v. 1.1. It has been fun since the beginning and extremely rewarding. Working with Ruby is a pleasure, much easier to learn than PHP, and the Rails framework is so well put together that you can, with little effort, produce some very elaborate web sites with advanced features all while learning how to do proper object oriented web programming.

I used my new knowledge to recreate from scratch the site of my [non-profit organization](http://yoga108.org/) (with a new domain ;-) and, with a friend who is a talented designer, created a [web development firm](http://ohlalaweb.com).

Don't get me wrong, it's not that easy, if you want to learn programming you need to put a lot of effort into it but in my own experience Rails can bring you some instant results while letting you get deeper and deeper over time.

I recommend two main sources of knowledge:

- The excellent, official [Rails
  guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/).
- The free screencasts
      from [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/).

Whatever your choice will be I wish you the best and a fun and fulfilling experience

Answer (score 0):

I recently came upon this question myself. I really liked the way PHP integrates with HTML making designing a site more natural in my opinion. Design your site as you would with static content and then switch the static with the dynamic. However, I wanted to choose a "good" language. I looked at PHP, Ruby, Perl, and Python, as they are the most popular, open source options. I didn't need any powerhorses, if you will, like Ruby on Rails or Django, since I just wanted to mess around with server side stuff and some SQL—nothing serious. I don't remember why nor do I care to remember why, but I chose Python. But I still wanted that integration with HTML. I came across [Karrigell](http://karrigell.sourceforge.net/). It's a neat piece of Python that essentially handles the integration. It comes with a little web server which you can use on its own or use something like mod_proxy with lighttpd. The devs don't limit you to only Python inside HTML, though. Their server parses: Python inside HTML, HTML inside Python, plain ol' Python scripts, and Karrigell services. It may not integrate as well as PHP does, but it's pretty damn good.